# How to import cjs aliased module when using vite?

Tags: javascript, configuration, vite

I have a local `.cjs` module locally on `../dist` folder which is aliased.

My vite.config.js looks like this:

```js
export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],

    resolve: {
      alias: [
        {
          find: '@my-local-cjs-module',
          replacement: resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        },
      ],
    },

    root: resolve(__dirname),
  });
};
```

In my `App.ts` file I have:

```
import { name } from '@my-local-cjs-module/my/path/index'
```

When I run the project I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/[..]dist/my/path/index.js' does not provide an export named 'name'
```

but the `index` file of the common js module contains:

```js
"use strict";Object.defineProperty(exports,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"});const e=require("../../index-svHKmGQ-.js");exports.name=e.name;
```

Does anybody have an idea on what's the problem here or how I could solve it?